# Best way to convert numeric date to textual format

Tags: javascript

I am retrieving data from an external API, the date information I got back is in the format of `'2018-05-06'`, what it the best way to convert it to `'May 6'` without the year?

Comment: Use https://momentjs.com/

Comment: You pass it to the date class. `new Date(mydate);` and you can extract month day year or anything you want from it: `date.getMonth(); date.getDate();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `months` array and use `split` method in order to find out the *month* and the *day*.

```js
let months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'], date = '2018-05-06';
let [_, month, day] = date.split('-');
console.log(`${months[month - 1]} ${ + day}`);
```

Comment: This method works best and doesn't have to use any dependencies like momentjs. and it's only 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here each with pros and cons.

### Moment.js

This is a very simple solution, and if you already have the dependency anyway it's a great solution.

```
const date = moment('2018-05-06').format('MMMM D');
```

#### Pros

- Simple
- Clean
- Easy to read
- Let's you know if the date is invalid (like `2018-05-32`)
- If your formatting needs change, it has a sophisticated formatter
- Easy to support other languages/locales

#### Cons

- Extra dependency that may be unnecessary
- If you don't want to validate the date, it may be overkill

### Javascript `Date`

```
const MONTHS = ['January', 'February', ...];
const date = new Date('2018-05-06');
const myString = MONTHS[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate();
```

#### Pros

- Pretty much the same pros as Moment.js, except for language handling
- No external dependencies

#### Cons

- If you don't need validation and are very performance sensitive, may be overkill
- Slightly awkward needing to store own representation of months

### Manual parsing

*See Mihai's answer*

#### Pros

- Can be high performance

#### Cons

- The code will likely be very specific to this requirement and not so easy to change if things get more sophisticated
- No date validation

Comment: You're welcome! If you're happy with one of these answers, do remember to "accept" it. Cheers!